# ¿Como puedo capturar los datos de un formulario html, procesarlo con azure function y enviar un correo?

Tags: javascript, azure

Tengo un formulario simple hecho en html5 y css (los campos son "nombre" y "email"), creé una azure function en javascript que se debe encargar de tomar los datos del formulario, procesarlos y enviar un correo electrónico al mismo correo que el usuario ingrese utilizando sendgrid, alguna idea de como hacerlo?...este es el código de mi azure function.

```
module.exports = async function (context, input) {
context.log(input);

var message = {
    "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "test@gmail.com" } ] } ],
   from: { email: "testfrom@gmail.com" },        
   subject: "Azure news",
   content: [{
       type: 'text/plain',
       value: input
   }]
```

};

context.done(null, message);
}

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hecha un vistazo a esto https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail

Comment: Desde HTML directo puedes poner el codigo javascript no necesitas poner eso en una azure function, puedes crear una logic app para enviar tu email eso seria mas simple y desde tu formulario HTML llamar el endpoint de la logic app: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres

Comment: Si te basas en este ejemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wilcorrea/ygkhmatq/
y creas un http logic app que envie el email.. solo tendrias que reemplazar la URL del ejemplo jsfiddle... url y tambien poner la key para tu logic app